# playframework 2.3.x not found: value helpers

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Got this error when started a new application with scala and was following the following documentation: [Scala Forms](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms). The life cycle image at the top is referring to `@import helpers._` whereas this should be `@import helper._`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter this error due to following the image under "Form Basics" of playframework documentation then just replace `@import helpers._` with `@import helper._`. This is mentioned in the documentation but the image took me off and only realize it later. I think the play team should update the image to avoid throwing others.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The link is there as tile `Scala Forms`.

Comment: This is the link, in the image import says to import helpers but it should be helper https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms